# Unable to write SSRS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

My query result set is:

```
Eid Cycle1 Cycle2 Cycle3 Cycle4 CountOfCycle
 1   0.75    0      0      0         2
```

The result in the SSRS report should be:

```
Eid Cycle1 Cycle2 Cycle3 Cycle4 CountOfCycle
 1   0.75    1      0      0         2
```

Depending on the countofcycles, 0s should be converted to 1s in the SSRS report.If there is a value already for the cycle, it should be left in that cycle. Another example:

```
Eid Cycle1 Cycle2 Cycle3 Cycle4 CountOfCycle
 1   0.75    0      0      0         3
```

SSRS report would be:

```
Eid Cycle1 Cycle2 Cycle3 Cycle4 CountOfCycle
 1   0.75    1      1      0         3
```

I am unable to code it in SSRS using expression.Depending on the value of CountOfCycle I have to convert 0s to 1s. CountOfCycle is the number of cycles with some value other than 0.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding the correct expression since you can't describe it accurately.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your criteria is, but I *think* the expression would be:

Cycle2:

```
If(Cycle2 = 0 AndAlso CountOfCycle >= 2, 1, Cycle2)
```

Cycle3:

```
If(Cycle3 = 0 AndAlso CountOfCycle >= 3, 1, Cycle3)
```

And so on...

Comment: Not all 0s should be 1s. If there is a value in cycle2 and rest of them are 0s. If the CountOfCycles is 3, then only two of the three 0s should be 1s, leaving one cycle as 0.

Comment: @MikeCraford Right - I flipped the logic to make it an expression - Cycle2 should be 1 if it is 0 and CountOfCycle >= 2.  If that's not what you want then I don't understand the requirements.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the utilization of a machine. CountOfCycles represent number of workorders. Value 0.75 for cycle 1 means, the machine was down after 75% of the utilization. For cycle 2 and 3 machine was running fine. But since I got three workorders, they must be assigned to some other issue which did not shutdown the machine. Therefore, I should assign cycles 2 and 3 as 100% leaving cycle 4 as 0 since there was no workorder for cycle 4.